# Flutter ListView not working properly when adding widgets to List

Tags: listview, flutter

I have two ListView widgets in my code.  One shows a list (childrenGenerated) created this way:

```
List<Widget> childrenGenerated = List.generate(count, (int i) => Widget1());
```

where count is incremented on every press of the floatingActionButton

The second ListView shows a list that is initialized empty in the stateful widget, and updated with a new, added widget every time that the floatingActionButton is pressed as so:

```
onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            count++;           <-- incremented for childrenGenerated
            childrenAdded.add( <-- Widget1 added.
              Widget1(),
            );
          });
        },
```

I have printed out the results for both lists, and the childrenAdded looks exactly the same as childrenGenerated (including when I use a debugger... exactly the same) however, in the listView, only the childrenGenerated is actually rendered.

On difference that I noticed, when the list is generated for childrenGenerated, the "entered widget" printout is seen, indicating that it has been instantiated... however, this doesn't happen for the childrenAdded version.

In short, how could you make this code work with the childrenAdded method?  What's missing?

I created a dartpad to show what I'm seeing: https://dartpad.dev/d31da0c9b9d913de26ba3420074ddb07

Comment: build method runs every time when you called setState

Comment: yes, but both list views are in the same build method,

Comment: also, it seems to be the build method of the child widget (Widget1) that isn’t firing when the list is added to, versus generated

Comment: I always use ListView.builder when using list that can be added or removed. but that's interesting how it doesn't work as expected when using normal constructor ListView

Comment: I wish I had listened to you earlier... that was exactly the problem.  I don't think I'll ever use a regular ListView again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `ListView.builder` 
For demo, I add `Widget2` with different icon 
code snippet

```
ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemCount: childrenAdded.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return childrenAdded[index];
                })
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Widget> childrenAdded = [];
  int count = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> childrenGenerated = List.generate(count, (int i) => Widget1());
    print("childrenGenerated:$childrenGenerated");
    print("childrenAdded:$childrenAdded");
    print("----------------");
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('some title')),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: childrenGenerated,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemCount: childrenAdded.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return childrenAdded[index];
                }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            count++;
            childrenAdded.add(
              Widget2(),
            );
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Widget1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Widget1({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("entered widget");
    return Icon(
      Icons.image,
      size: 50,
    );
  }
}

class Widget2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Widget2({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("entered widget");
    return Icon(
      Icons.ac_unit,
      size: 50,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Man, oh man do I appreciate the help. This particular problem boggled my mind, and I started thinking that I wasn't under instantiations correction.  I appreciate your help to try and understand what's going on